# Wait for animation to complete before continuing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to wait for a jQuery animation to finish before proceeding with another command?

For example, I want to fade out/slide up an element, change some items within the element and then fade them back in/slide back down.

If I put the statements one after another, you can see the items change before the animation completes.

```
$('#item').fadeOut();
$('#item').html('Changed item');
$('#item').fadeIn();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass callback in `fadeIn/fadeOut`. [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

```
$('#item').fadeOut('slow', function(){

     $('#item').html('Changed item');
     $('#item').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either use the *callback* method which gets called from `.fadeOut`, like

```
$('#item').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $(this).html('Changed item').fadeIn();
});
```

or use the underlaying *Deferred object*

```
$('#item').fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
    $(this).html('Changed item').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a callback function to `fadeOut`.

```
$("#item").fadeOut(function() { 
                       $(this).html("changed").fadeIn();
                   });
```

This is the sort of thing you'll learn in a basic jQuery tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#item').fadeOut('slow', function() { // do your stuff here });
```

For more info: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut#speedcallback